# Is it unwise to use XCode 2.5 instead of 3.x/4.x?

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-tiger

I've been looking into **a cost-effective way to get into iOS App development**.  I'm thinking games now, but I could go in a lot of directions.

I've got a windows rig, and found a VMWare solution.  And although it's possible to [virtualize os-x on windows 7](http://techexxpert.blogspot.com/2010/12/how-to-virtualize-os-x-on-windows-7.html), I don't like the idea of using that much memory and downloading an OS from a shady torrent site.

I found a used mini mac, running Tiger for only $200 on amazon.  Specs are:

- 1.42 GHz PowerPC G4 processor with 167 MHz system bus
- 512 MB DDR SDRAM (expandable to 1 GB), 80 GB hard drive, slot-loading
  Combo Drive (DVD-ROM/CD-RW)
- Mac OS X version 10.4 Tiger, iLive '05, Mail, and more included

**It seems only XCode 2.5 runs on Tiger, you can't update to 3.x**.  (Apple offers [XCode 2.5](https://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?bundleID=19907) to registered developers)

So my question is -- would it be worth spending $200 more to get Snow Leopard (which is compatible with 3.x)?

---

Please define worthiness within at least a few of these criteria:

- Does XCode 2.5 have different performance than 3.x when compiled on
  iPad and iPhone?
- Are there any widely used/helpful [developer
  tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937645/what-tools-do-you-use-to-support-xcode) that you miss out on?
- Would the performance of a used Tiger mini mac be painful to develop
  XCode with (not going to be doing anything other than developing on
  it, any comments about performance?)
- Would Apple reject you from the app marketplace for using the
  outdated compiler (I haven't finished the 50-page manifesto that is the Apple Developer agreement...)?

Thanks to anyone who answers.

Comment: Officially, the iOS tools require a x86 Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were me I'd try and find newer hardware. I've written some things for iOS on an x86_64 MacBook originally running Leopard, currently running Snow Leopard. It's slow on both. I can't imagine how slow it would be on a G4.

I think there might be a limit on what version of iOS the Apple App store accepts, but am not sure what it is.  I do suspect the limit is greater than 1.x. :-).